# rule to redirect to a specific port on htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

How can I specify a rule to redirect requests to a certain port?

Here's my existing `.htaccess` file.

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On

# Some servers require you to specify the `RewriteBase` directive
# In such cases, it should be the path (relative to the document root)
# containing this .htaccess file
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.ini$
RewriteRule \.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

By default, it is being redirected to 80.

I tried to add a following line to the file:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1\:2222%{REQUEST_URI}" [P,QSA,L]
```

I get easily confused with .htaccess rules.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with VirtualHost? and there is both are the same domain?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes they both are in the same domain (192.168.11.32).
And no, I haven't tried it in the VirtualHost.

Comment: When do you want to redirect on port 2222? Is there any speciation URL or file(condition)?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I want to change the port for whole application. No specific conditions.

Comment: Then you can change configure httpd.conf file. Or you need to via htaccess?